# Automate changing code from method to property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, optimization, ide

I'm attempting to clean up a source code written by someone who is proficient at Java but had zero working knowledge in C#.

For now, I'd like to change the get/set methods in data objects into properties with getters and setters. What's a good way to automate such task?

Here's an example. I'd like to change the following line

```
sPcDataDTO.SetInputTimeString(row["DATA_ITIME"].ToString());
```

Into this

```
sPcDataDTO.InputTime = row["DATA_ITIME"].ToString();
```

Find/Replace won't really work, as the name of the method SetInputTimeString is used in other classes and I also need to remove the extra bracket at the end

Comment: i don't think there is a tool that will do that for you.

Comment: @DanielA.White That was my hunch as well, but people at StackOverflow have pleasantly surprised me many times. Maybe someone else knows a creative solution :)?

Comment: I wrote about 4000 lines of ASM with less than 20 lines of Python a few days ago.  Depending on how consistent the pattern is in the "before" versus "after" in your case, Python might be able to help here as well.  It's still a find and replace, but just that you can be very detailed in Python what to find in the input file and how to replace it for the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your methods one by one with Resharper and his function "[Convert method to property](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Refactorings__Convert_Method_to_Property.html)". But it can not convert all in once

Comment: Wow I had resharper and I didn't even know about this feature. Thanks a lot!